# Duplicating a set of columns with various widths within the same spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to duplicate a set of 5 columns multiple times on the same sheet.  For example, column A is wide, columns B & E are medium width and Columns C & D are narrow.  I want to duplicate this width format multiple times in the adjoining columns.  Is that possible without having to manually adjust each column?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Google Spreadsheets doesn't consider column width a format that can be copied. `Paint format` and selecting the entire column don't work.